# Query related to Memsql

Tags: singlestore

I recently upgraded our V5 cluster to V6.7.
After the upgrade I would like to start using memsql-tools/memsql-admin but was very frustrate not to find any clear cut documentation on how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We recently added a migration guide for moving to memsql-tools/memsql-admin: https://docs.memsql.com/v6.8/guides/cluster-management/ops-to-tools/. Hope that answers your questions.